# check_admin_referer not working in custom meta box for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, security, nonce

In my callback function (the one which output HTML for forms) of `add_meta_box`, I am using

```
wp_nonce_field( 'uniqueid', 'my_nonce' )
```

Now in saving function, I am using this at top to verify nonce

```
check_admin_referer( 'uniqueid', 'my_nonce' )
```

But due to this, I am getting below error as soon as I hit the `Add New` button
`Are you sure you want to do this?` (Its 403 default error message )

For now I am using `wp_verify_nonce`, but I don't understand why above code is not working?
*Note: I am adding this meta box to a custom post type*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now in saving function ...

in which hook ? if you do this in "save_post_CPT", it doesn't work because this hook is called a first time a the object creation

then you have to do this :

```
add_action("save_post_CPT", function ($object_ID, \WP_Post $object, $update) {

    if (!$update) {

        // new object, here you can define default values



        return;

    }



    if (isset($_REQUEST["uniqueid"])) {

        check_admin_referer(
              "uniqueid"
            , "my_nonce"
        );



        // saving informations of the metabox


    }


    // here the code when the object is put in the trash or with quick edit e.g.




}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you, It Works. Can I get further reference of this implementation so that I can learn in more depth ?